# Pandas - explode a column and set a specific value to a column for replicated rows

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-explode

I would like to explode a column `Col1` of a dataframe and for all the replicated rows, set a specific value `z` for a given column `Col2`.

For example if my dataframe `df` is:

| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [A,B,C] | x | y |

I would like to find a way using `df.explode("Col1")` and achieve:

| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | x | y |
| B | z | y |
| C | z | y |

Thank you for any idea.

Comment: why is the logic behind the z characters?

Comment: x, y and z are just dummy variables

Comment: so would you supply a list of values in `Col1` that you would like to change in `Col2`?

Comment: No, `Col1` is the column that I want to explode. A, B and C are also dummy variables.

Comment: If you use `df.explode('Col1')` then `Col1` will have A,B,C, `Col2` will have all x's and `Col3` will have all y's. What is the logic for the z's to come in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```py
out = (df.explode('Col1')
       .groupby(level=0)
       .apply(lambda g: g.assign(Col2=[g['Col2'].iloc[0]]+['z']*(len(g)-1)))  # keep first row of Col2 and replace rest with z
       .reset_index(drop=True))
```

```
print(out)

  Col1 Col2 Col3
0    A    x    y
1    B    z    y
2    C    z    y
```

Comment: Thanks it works great. Nice use of apply/assign!